# Fixed length DIV inline with a percentage length DIV?

Tags: html, css, width, percentage

Sorry for the vague title, wording this problem is difficult.
Observe the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .float
            {
                float:left;
                display:inline-block;
                height:50px;
            }

            #a
            {
                width:80%;
                background-color:lightgrey;
            }

            #b
            {
                width:20%;
                background-color:lightblue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="float" id="a">The width of this div should adjust depending on the screen size.</div>
        <div class="float" id="b">The width of this div should stay the same regardless of screen size.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run this, the width of DIVs "**a**" and "**b**" change depending on the screen size as you would expect with percentages, but I want DIV "**b**" stay a fixed width (like 50 pixels), whilst still allowing DIV "**a**" to fill the space between the leftside of the screen and the left edge of DIV "**b**".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `calc(100% - 50px)`:

### Demo on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/0or0cvmw/1/)

```
.float {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
}

#a {
    -webkit-width: calc(100% - 50px);
    width: calc(100% - 50px);
    background-color:lightgrey;
}

#b {
    width:50px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with container with `display:table;` and `display: table-cell;` for the childs here example

http://jsfiddle.net/cs0wor4y/

Answer (score 0):

Simple with pure js,Use this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
        .float
        {
            float:left;
            display:inline-block;
            height:50px;
        }

        #a
        {
            background-color:lightgrey;
        }

        #b
        {
            background-color:lightblue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="float" id="a">The width of this div should increase depending on the screen size.</div>
        <div class="float" id="b">The width of this div should stay the same depending on screen size.</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    width = window.innerWidth;
    height = window.innerHeight;
    console.log(width);
    console.log(height);
    var a= document.getElementById('a');
    var b= document.getElementById('b');
    aa=width-50-20;//20 is for browser default padding removal.
    console.log(aa);
    a.style.width=aa+"px";
    b.style.width=50+"px";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: @chipChocolate.py is also better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `calc` isn't supported in older browsers, so I think you'll have more like with simple `floats`. The setup is really simple, and you can just change the `float` and `margin` direction if you want `b` to be on the left side.

Fiddle with the example is located here: http://jsfiddle.net/ax6wo2qv/

```
.container {
    margin-right:50px;
}
#b {
    float:right;
    width:50px;
    margin-right:-50px;
}
#a {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
```